# What does a violin mute do?

Tags: violin

Recently, I bought a brand new violin. As I was looking at the parts that came with it, I saw a part called a *violin mute*. What does that *violin mute* do?

Comment: There are two types of mute, a concert mute and a practice mute. Which do you mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A violin mute fits over the bridge and dampens vibrations making the violin sound quieter. As simple as that.

Comment: As well as making the sound quieter, it changes the timbre significantly. I always preferred the muted sound when practicing...

Comment: I had to resist the temptation to answer "It mutes a violin."

Answer (score 3):

Violin muted make it easier to play music quite without annoying people nearby. Alongside being used to quite the sounds of the violin, violin mute are also often used in pieces of music. Some music pieces specifically suggests to use a violin mute. For example, this piece, Arlington Sketches, it specifically tells us to use a mute in certain parts.

[image]

Here, before measure 96, you have to put on the violin mute.

[image]

And take it off after measure 126.